# bisect a data frame according to median of each column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a numeric data frame with many columns.
I would like to bisect it into groups based on whether an observation is above or below the median in each axis.

For example:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data_frame(x = c(rnorm(5, 1, 0.1), rnorm(5, 3, 0.1), 
                       rnorm(5, 1, 0.1), rnorm(5, 3, 0.1)), 
                 y = c(rnorm(5, -1, 0.1), rnorm(5, 5, 1), 
                       rnorm(5, 5, 1), rnorm(5, -1, 0.1)))
```

Here I should obtain 4 groups: the points around (1,5), the points around (1,-1), and so on.

I can do this with `ifelse`, and define the limits of each area, but in practice I will have many columns. Is there a simpler `dplyr`/BaseR solution?

Comment: Please use `set.seed` for functions such as `rnorm` to keep reproducibility. Also can we see the `ifelse` solution of yours?

Comment: Here's a start: `mutate_all(df, funs(above_med = . > median(.)))`

Comment: Thanks! this solved it

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full answer to the question, building on the important input from @docendo discimus:

```
df <- df %>% mutate_all(funs(above_med = . > median(.)))
df <- df %>% mutate(Group = df %>% group_by_at(which(sapply(df, class) == "logical")) %>% group_indices())
```

The output looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 20 x 5
     x      y x_above_med y_above_med Group
   <dbl>  <dbl> <lgl>       <lgl>       <int>
   0.743 -0.983 FALSE       FALSE           1
   0.996 -0.901 FALSE       FALSE           1
   0.966 -1.00  FALSE       FALSE           1
   1.06  -1.18  FALSE       FALSE           1
   0.948 -0.971 FALSE       FALSE           1
   3.02   5.45  TRUE        TRUE            4
   3.19   5.59  TRUE        TRUE            4
   3.08   5.37  TRUE        TRUE            4
   3.04   3.61  TRUE        TRUE            4
   2.97   5.85  TRUE        TRUE            4
   0.969  5.27  FALSE       TRUE            2
   1.11   5.40  FALSE       TRUE            2
   1.12   5.62  FALSE       TRUE            2
   1.17   4.59  FALSE       TRUE            2
   0.899  6.19  FALSE       TRUE            2
   3.01  -0.987 TRUE        FALSE           3
   3.01  -0.963 TRUE        FALSE           3
   2.85  -1.07  TRUE        FALSE           3
   2.96  -1.00  TRUE        FALSE           3
   3.00  -0.927 TRUE        FALSE           3
```